# Flask-SQLAlchemy relationship error (relation "table_name" does not exist)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a foreign key (one-to-many relationship) between User_Info table and the rest tables, but it gives me this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable)
>   relation "user_info" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO user_info
>   (username, first_name, last_name, gend...
>                       ^
>
> [SQL: INSERT INTO user_info (username, first_name, last_name, gender,
>   date_of_birth, profile_img_url) VALUES (%(username)s, %(first_name)s,
>   %(last_name)s, %(gender)s, %(date_of_birth)s, %(profile_img_url)s)
>   RETURNING user_info.id] [parameters: {'username': 'gohammedhl',
>   'first_name': 'Ameer', 'last_name': 'Farqad', 'gender': '1',
>   'date_of_birth': '2019-09-25', 'profile_img_url': 'bla bla'}]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

And here are my tables:

```
class User_Info(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_info"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False)
    date_of_birth = db.Column(db.DATE, nullable=False)
    profile_img_url = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    post = db.relationship("Posts", backref="post_author", lazy=True)
    comment = db.relationship("Comments", backref="comment_author", lazy=True)
    phone_number = db.relationship("User_Auth", backref="ph_no_owner", lazy=True)

class User_Auth(UserMixin, db.Model):    
    __tablename__ = "user_auth"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone_no = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    ph_no_owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user_info.id"))

class Posts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id =  db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(400), nullable=True)
    post_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    post_author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user_info.id"))


class Comments(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "comments"
    id =  db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    comment_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    comment_author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user_info.id"))
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you ran database migrations after creating your models?

Comment: Actually no, I just initialized it

Comment: assuming you are using `Flask-Migrate`, you need to create migrations after you initialize using `flask db migrate` which will create migration files. Then you need to run those migration files using `flask db upgrade`

Comment: Actually I just recreated it using python interpreter and it worked like a charm!
But I still don't understand why it didn't work on the code editor yet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it!

It was lacking:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = ("postgresql://postgres:PasswordHere@localhost/dbName")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And:

```
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

Though this code was in a seperate file created for creating stuff, but it didn't work properly until I put it in the same file of the tables above!